# How to get path (or URL) to iTunes movies folder in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I can get URL of movies folder of my application like this:

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .moviesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

But I need to get URL of ALL movies folder on iPhone (which is synchronized with MacBook through iTunes). How to do it?

Comment: All movies folder? What folder is that?

Comment: Did you mean all the Videos in Photos app?